# Openerp Scheduler is working but the attached funciton not executing

Tags: python, odoo

I tried to execute a function using Openerp scheduler but it changed nothing. If I run the function only it works perfectly fine but not with the scheduler. Please help me with this.

in hr_holidays.xml file I added this,

```
<record id="ir_cron_scheduler" model="ir.cron">
  <field name="name">Casual Leave Allocation</field>
  <field name="interval_number">1</field>
  <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
  <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
  <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
  <field eval="'hr.holidays'" name="hr.holidays"/>
  <field eval="'allocate_on_probations'" name="allocate_on_probations"/>
  <field eval="'()'" name="args"/>
</record>
```

and with little adjustments UI looks like this;
[image]

[image]

[image]

The function

```
def allocate_on_probations(self, cr, uid, ids,tl, context=None):
    allo=0
    state='active'
    result = {}

    emps=self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('current_status','=','active')], context=context)
    if emps:    
        for r in emps:
            hol_state=2 
            gt_dt=cr.execute("""SELECT appointed_date FROM hr_employee WHERE id= %d order by id"""%(r))
            gt_dd=cr.fetchone()[0]

            #getting today details
            today = datetime.datetime.now()
            tt=today.date()
            td=tt.day
            tm=tt.month
            ty=tt.year

            #getting appointment date details
            app=datetime.datetime.strptime(gt_dd, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            #print app
            ay=app.year
            am=app.month
            ad=app.day

            if ay==ty:
                #compairing today and appointed date
                comp=(tt-app)
                chat=int(comp.days)
                chat_mod=chat%30
                print chat_mod
                print r

                if chat_mod==29:
                    hol_obj=self.pool.get('hr.holidays')
                    print hol_obj
                    condition_1=[('employee_id','=',r),('type','=','add'),('holiday_status_id','=',hol_state)]
                    hol_emp=hol_obj.search(cr, uid,condition_1, context=context)

                    if hol_emp:                
                        for n in hol_emp:
                            hol_dt=cr.execute("""SELECT number_of_days_temp FROM hr_holidays WHERE id= %d order by id"""%(n))
                            hol_dd=cr.fetchone()[0]
                            hol_inc=(hol_dd+0.5)

                            print hol_inc
                            cr.execute("""UPDATE hr_holidays SET number_of_days_temp= %d WHERE id= %d"""%(hol_inc,n))
                            cr.execute("""UPDATE hr_holidays SET number_of_days= %d  WHERE id= %d"""%(hol_inc,n))

    return True
```

Comment: Are your crons running?

Comment: Can you show us that function ? and also make sure there is no error in log while that cron is running.

Comment: now uploaded the function

Comment: What is t1 in that function ?and how you passed to that function from cron ?

Comment: I checked the function only as a on-change function for a check box, for that I used t1. By doing it like that it changed the leave allocation. Then after as in ,http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/schedulers-openerp , I changed the xml file.
Other than that do I  need to create new cron for that ? Please help me

Comment: See I have posted detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set default value for that parameter and no need to pass it via cron, and if it is required in function the pass it from the cron.

```
def allocate_on_probations(self, cr, uid, ids,tl=False, context=None):

        allo=0
        state='active'
        result = {}


        emps=self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('current_status','=','active')], context=context)
        if emps:

            for r in emps:
                hol_state=2 
                gt_dt=cr.execute("""SELECT appointed_date FROM hr_employee WHERE id= %d order by id"""%(r))
                gt_dd=cr.fetchone()[0]

                #getting today details
                today = datetime.datetime.now()
                tt=today.date()
                td=tt.day
                tm=tt.month
                ty=tt.year

                #getting appointment date details
                app=datetime.datetime.strptime(gt_dd, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                #print app
                ay=app.year
                am=app.month
                ad=app.day

                if ay==ty:
                    #compairing today and appointed date
                    comp=(tt-app)
                    chat=int(comp.days)
                    chat_mod=chat%30
                    print chat_mod
                    print r

                    if chat_mod==29:
                        hol_obj=self.pool.get('hr.holidays')
                        print hol_obj
                        condition_1=[('employee_id','=',r),('type','=','add'),('holiday_status_id','=',hol_state)]
                        hol_emp=hol_obj.search(cr, uid,condition_1, context=context)

                        if hol_emp:

                            for n in hol_emp:
                                hol_dt=cr.execute("""SELECT number_of_days_temp FROM hr_holidays WHERE id= %d order by id"""%(n))
                                hol_dd=cr.fetchone()[0]
                                hol_inc=(hol_dd+0.5)

                                print hol_inc
                                cr.execute("""UPDATE hr_holidays SET number_of_days_temp= %d WHERE id= %d"""%(hol_inc,n))
                                cr.execute("""UPDATE hr_holidays SET number_of_days= %d  WHERE id= %d"""%(hol_inc,n))




        return True
```

And if it is mandatory then you need to pass t1 value from the cron in **args**

[image]

Comment: The thing is even though I did above steps the scheduler runs, as its time changes but method defined in scheduler don't run.

Comment: Can you please set the break point in to the method and set the scheduler after 1 min and check whether control is coming there in method or not ?

Comment: It worked... I really don't have any idea how it happens but I removed the parameter from the function but kept the Arguments:- (True,) as it is.

Thank you so much for the kind support